# Cover page of my passport damaged

Tags: air-travel, passports, indian-citizens

[image]
This image of the crack in my passport's cover page. It was pointed out as damaged by VFS global at New Delhi.Will it cause rejection? I have applied for Estonia visa for conference.

Comment: Visa is unlikely to be rejected but you should apply for reissue of passport because of damage. You can travel with new passport and visa on old one.

Comment: @user82415 What did you end up doing? If you got a re-issued passport, did you have to get the visa stamped also?